# How to join two columns to the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table called messages, it has three columns

```
1. UserFrom uniqueidentifier
2. UserTo uniqueidentifier
3. Messagen varchar(50)
```

This table is used to store messages sent from one user to another, it stores the `UserId` from the `aspnet_Users` instead of the `username`, now I need to create a view that shows the `UserFrom` and `UserTo` as names by getting the `Usename` from the `aspnet_Users` table using the `UserId` in the table messages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have tagged the question both mysql and sql-server. Which is it?

Comment: And what problem are you having? What code are you trying? What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join aspnet_Users table twice with different alias names:

```
SELECT U1.Username as UserFrom,U2.Username as UserTo, M.Message
FROM Messages M JOIN
     aspnet_Users U1 ON U1.UserId=M.UserFrom JOIN
     aspnet_Users U2 ON U2.UserId=M.UserTo
```

**Explanation:**

Here aspnet_Users table it joined twice with different alias names U1,U2. And each username is fetched from the respective table.

Answer (score 1):

Just join with the user table twice.

```
SELECT
  t2.name AS userFrom,
  t3.name AS userTo,
  t1.Message
FROM messages t1
LEFT JOIN aspnet_Users t2 ON t1.UserFrom = t2.UserId
LEFT JOIN aspnet_Users t3 ON t1.UserTo = t3.UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join twice to the table with the user data - once for each user involved:

```
select uf.username from_username, ut.username to_username, message
from messages m
join aspnet_Users uf on uf.id = userfrom
join aspnet_Users ut on ut.id = userto
```

This sql will work in both databases you have tagged the question with (or any other).